# How do i get total duration of timestamps in mysql?

Tags: mysql, time

I have a table, that gives a timestamp for a scan made by a user with what tool. Columns are `scan_time`, `login_name`.  The table only gives a timestamp for when the scan took place, so treating the first scan made by the user as the start time, and the last scan made as the end time, how do i get the total duration between scans for users?

```
SELECT scan_time, login_name
FROM table1
WHERE scan_time >= CURDATE()
```

Results in this table

```
|      scan_time      |  login_name  |  
| 2021-04-29 10:15:20 |    jacob     |     
| 2021-04-29 10:14:35 |    jacob     |    
| 2021-04-29 10:13:00 |    jacob     |    
| 2021-04-29 09:50:49 |    Matt      |    
| 2021-04-29 09:30:13 |    Matt      |    
| 2021-04-29 09:25:38 |    jacob     |      
| 2021-04-29 09:20:00 |    jacob     |  
| 2021-04-29 09:15:46 |    Matt      |    
| 2021-04-29 09:13:57 |    Matt      |   
| 2021-04-29 09:10:35 |    jacob     |   
| 2021-04-29 09:08:38 |    jacob     |   
| 2021-04-29 09:08:24 |    Matt      |   
| 2021-04-29 09:05:11 |    Matt      |
```

I need to total time spent scanning for each user. Example `login_name` (jacob) had his first scan at `2021-04-29 09:08:38` and his last scan was at `2021-04-29 10:15:20`. jacobs total duration should be 67 minutes after rounding.

```
|      total_time     |  login_name  | 
|      67 minutes     |     jacob    |  
|      46 minutes     |     Matt     |
```

Comment: Use `MAX(scan_time) - MIN(scan_time)` to get the duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  Group by the login_name, then use timestampdiff to get the number of seconds between the min scan_time and max scan_time, then divide by 60 to get minutes.

```
SELECT login_name, 
    timestampdiff(second, min(scan_time), max(scan_time)) / 60 as elapsed
FROM table1
WHERE scan_time >= CURDATE() 
GROUP BY login_name
```

You can also make the interval hour instead of second if you only need integer level precision: `timestampdiff(hour, min(scan_time), max(scan_time))`

Please see the attached fiddle for an example.  I did replace CURDATE() with '2021-04-29' since none of the sample date is actually greater than or equal to CURDATE().

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3699db3/2

Comment: Is there a way to add in an additional grouping? such as `login_name` (jacob) had 45 minutes of scans for `tool_function` (pick) and 22 minutes of scans for `tool_function` (inventory) and still group it by `login_name`?

Comment: sure, just add the column you want to group by to the `SELECT` section of the query and also to the `GROUP BY`

Comment: To further add to it. if there is a `zone` added in, and say `login_name` spent 10 minutes of pick in 'general' zone, 25 minutes of pick in 'cold' zone, and the last 10 minutes in 'general'. I end up with a result of 45 minutes pick function for general, and 25 minutes pick function in cold. how do i get it to give me the accurate 20 minutes general?

Comment: Why don't you create a fiddle that has some sample data in it and send me the link, and I can write in a query.  It's not hard, but it's probably easier to write it out there than in the comments.  Plus it will help to see the data you're talking about and the layout.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e55063/2/0 here is the sample code @chris

Comment: actually, that might be a little tricky.  Let's get clear about exactly what you want as far as your desired output, can you give me the fields you would want produced in the output?  And what's your mySQL version?

Comment: current mySQL version is whatever the more recent one is as far as i know. desired output example would be, if possible, `login_name` (jacob), `tool_function` (pick), `zone` (cold), `elapsed` (21.5). If `tool_function` needs to be dropped from the output thats fine. the main goal is to at least discern the total time of scans in `zone` per `login_name`, and the example having (jacob) have a break from (cold) via (general) in the middle, needs to be broken up. Current code as is includes (general) in the total time for (cold).